# For any ideal $I \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(X)$ the set $\{x \in X: f(x) = 0 \text{ for all }f \in I\}$ is not empty?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, commutative-algebra

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522951/example-for-some-x-of-a-nonclosed-ideal-in-mathbbcx#) for a related question by someone else.

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $\mathbb{C}(X)$ the algebra of continuous functions $f: X \to \mathbb{C}$, with pointwise operations. Does it follow that for any ideal $I \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(X)$ the set$$\{x \in X: f(x) = 0 \text{ for all }f \in I\}$$ is not empty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is true.

First you should consider finitely many elements $f_1, \dotsc, f_n \in I$. Assume they have no common zero. Then the function $f=\sum f_i\overline{f_i}$ has no zero, hence $f$ is a unit. On the other hand $f \in I$, contradiction!

To get a common zero for all elements of $I$, we have to - of course - use compactness: To find a suitable open cover, which does the trick, note that the following is true for any set $M \subset \mathbb C(X)$:

$$ \text{ The elements in } M \text{ have no common zero} \Leftrightarrow \bigcap_{f \in M} f^{-1}(\{0\}) = \emptyset \Leftrightarrow \bigcup_{f \in M} f^{-1}(\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}) = X$$

Comment: You can use the FIP closed set property on $X$ for the collection $Z(f) = f^{-1}[\{0\}], f \in I$

Comment: Nice and simple, +1